# how to calculate sum score only for items where NA < 50%

Tags: r, na, psych

I am quite new to R and I am trying to calculate subscores for psychological tests (e.g. PedsQL) and don't know how to create the subscores respecting the following conditions from the authors about the `NA`'s:

**"If more than 50% of the items are missing, the scale scores should not be computed.
If 50% or more items are completed: impute the mean of the completed items on a scale."**

For example one subscore is the physical dimension with 8 items:

```
d$pedsql_phys = (d$pedsql_1 + d$pedsql_2 + d$pedsql_3 + d$pedsql_4 + d$pedsql_5 + d$pedsql_6 + d$pedsql_7 + d$pedsql_8)/8
```

I tried to use the `scoreItems` function of the `psych` package, but it did not work. Probably a `for-if-loop` would be better, however, I don't know how to do it. 
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this where `DF` is the input data frame:

```
ifelse(rowSums(is.na(DF)) > ncol(DF)/2, NA, rowMeans(DF, na.rm = TRUE))
```